# ¿Cómo crear un diccionario de traducción en android studio?

Tags: android-studio, base-de-datos, string

Quiero crear un **diccionario** (de tipo **español-inglés**; inglés-español) en android studio y poner un editText para **buscar** palabras. No sé si es posible hacerlo usando *String*, o debería usar base de datos.

Si alguien pudiera darme el empujón inicial...

gracias!

Comment: Debes usar una base de datos. La base de datos que usa android por defecto es sqlite. [Enlace informativo](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/10/android-sqlite-bases-de-datos/)

Comment: Parece interesante la información. Pero nunca había trabajado con sqlite, así que voy a intentarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Podes crear un diccionario de varias maneras.
Un de ella es sin usar base de datos. Solo usamos una clase Map.

```
Map <String,String> map =  new HashMap<String, String>();
// Agergar items 
map.put("rojo","red");

// Obtener items 
String employeeName =(String) map.get("rojo");
```

La otra es usando SQLlite. Existen muchos ejemplos en internet. Te paso un [link](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/10/android-sqlite-bases-de-datos/) que te va a servir